# Cannot convert to JSON object in android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I want to create Android Client Application that consume JSON based asmx web service from asp.net Server Application.My server code return JSON fromat result . And I tried the sample code from Internet.It is convenient.But with my own server application ("http://stockcluster.com/CurrentPeriod.asmx/GetGrowthPersentage") the following error is appeared instead of JSON object:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title></title>

<script src="http://ak2.imgaft.com/script/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.ajax({ url: 'https://mcc.godaddy.com/parked/park.aspx/?q=pFHmpJMaLaO4pUybMzqlMF5j
    LabyZwMzqaRyZ3RlAwt0ZGN3ZPHlAzA2pFHmpGRmAmN2BGRkBQp0AGp0AwHmAQDyZwMyMlHmpG
    VjZGZkZQN3ZQZ0AmZlWGV2L3xyZ3Rk-1', dataType: 'jsonp', type: 'GET', jsonpCallback: 'parkcallback',

    success: function (data) { if (data["returnval"] != null) { window.location.href = 'http://stockcluster.com?nr=' + data["returnval"]; } 
    else { window.location.href = 'http://stockcluster.com?hg=0' } }});});
</script></head><body></body></html>

 Value <html of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Please give me some suggestions.

Edit:
my server code is here :

```
[WebMethod]
    public void HelloWorld() {
        String j = "Hello World";
        Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { j }));
    }
```

output JSON is here:

```
{"j":"Hello World"}
```

Comment: Could you provide any server code? This is no JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I use to embed [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library in my projects.

You can use the following method to read Objects from JSON:

```
Type ulist = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourCustomObject>>() {
                }.getType();
ArrayList<YourCustomObject> a = gson.fromJson(jsonStringFromYourRequest, ulist);
```

Comment: My problem is parsing JSON Object from my own server side.

Answer (score 0):

I typed this on browser

https://mcc.godaddy.com/parked/park.aspx/?q=pFHmpJMaLaO4pUybMzqlMF5jLabyZwMzqaRyZ3RlAwt0ZGN3ZPHlAzA2pFHmpGRmAmN2BGRkBQp0AGp0AwHmAQDyZwMyMlHmpGVjZGZkZQN3ZQZ0AmZlWGV2L3xyZ3Rk-1

It returned a file named park and had output { returnval: -1 }.

Did you try to generate the wsdl?  Why don't you paste the client code (Android code)"?

Comment: What is your server application? PHP or ASP.NET ?I used ASP.NET application for server side and android for client side.And you only need to fix your server side, not client side.Your output is not JSON.Please show me your server code if asp.net.